# Alpha-sorting multiple rows, empty cells for missing values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

Say I have multiple columns:

```
A    | B    | C…
Bill | Bill | John
Adam | Fran | Nick
     | Adam2| Adam
```

I’d like to alpha sort the rows in each column, and also add empty values in a cell if the cell does not have the same value as its row-sibling cells. The result would look like:

```
A    | B     | C…
Adam |       | Adam
     | Adam2 |
Bill | Bill  | 
     | Fran  |
     |       | John
     |       | Nick
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far to accomplish your ask? If you want to do the sort in the same table, then you'll need VBA, if the output can be a different table then, probably power query, or some type of lambda formula.

Comment: I’m not familiar enough with Excel/Sheets to even know what to mess around with, tbh. I’ve considered doing this in Python (Pandas or something similar), which is more familiar to me, but I’m trying to share this with non-programmers. I was hoping there was some magical function native to Sheets/Excel that could do this already.

Comment: Questions about "google-spreadsheets" are off-topic because it's a web app. The question includes nothing about Google Sheets; [tag:google-spreadsheets] should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

In Excel 365 you can use formula like this:

```
=LET(clr,TRIM($A$2:$C$4), wbl,SORT(UNIQUE(TOCOL(clr))),
 list,FILTER(wbl,wbl<>""), MAKEARRAY(ROWS(list),COLUMNS(clr),
 LAMBDA(r,c,LET(col,CHOOSECOLS(clr,c),a,INDEX(list,r),
 IF(ISERROR(MATCH(a,col,0)),"",a)))))
```

[image: Sort3cols]

In place of `$A$2:$C$4` you put the address of your data range. You can also convert this formula into `LAMBDA` with one argument.

Comment: This can be shorten by adding optional ignore blanks modifer in the `TOCOL()` formula.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I don't know if I understood your intention correctly, but I think the possibility of shortening this formula depends on the form of the data. The `TOCOL` function with optional parameter `1` allows you to skip empty cells, but not empty texts. The data prepared by the OP contained spaces that had to be filtered out, resulting in empty texts.